# How do I undo the most recent commits in Git?

Tags: windows, git, terminal

I am not able to undo the commits in git. It shows technical errors while doing so.

I have tried to navigate to the folder for my git repo and expecting to solve the problem at the earliest.

Comment: More details please, like the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

command:

```
git revert HEAD
```

you can mention the commit ID to revert the commit, if mentioned HEAD it will revert the last commit